# Linq group by query

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to work out a linq query and was wondering if you guys could help.

I have a list of objects `foo` and each `foo` object has a list of `bar`. bar has an active date and a numeric value. for example

```
foo
   bar -> 01/02/05, 10000
   bar -> 04/06/10, 30023
foo
   bar -> 30/01/02, 23494
```

And I want to write a linq query that will return me a distinct list of dates and the summed total for that date

It may be that its friday, but I'm drawing a blank.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Looks like you want:

```
var query = from foo in list
            from bar in foo.Bars
            group bar.Value by bar.Date into dates
            select new { Date = dates.Key, Sum = dates.Sum() };
```

Comment: yep, thats the ticket... think I need to go home

Comment: @brokem, I'm after the summed total, not the number of dates

Comment: @mjmcloug: Yep I realized that once I had already written the comment - removed it right after.

Answer (score 6):

Check it as well...

```
var q = from e in Entries
          select new
          {
               EntryID = e.EntryID,
               EntryName = e.EntryName,
               EntryDescription = e.EntryDescription,
               VoterID = voterID,
               Score = (int?)(from v in e.Votes
                              where v.VoterID == voterID 
                              select v.Score).FirstOrDefault()
```