# How to write Nested LINQ for specific scenario

Tags: c#, linq

Apologized to post a problem for which i could not construct anything solid. it is very shameful for me to post like this kind of question even after having so high reputation for this web site.

Most of the time i write sql in store procedure in sql server and hardly use LINQ. so facing problem to construct a nested LINQ query for a specific scenario. just wonder if anyone could help me or give me hints to construct such query with linq.

here i am providing a sample sql query which i want to construct the same one with LINQ.

```
SELECT EmployeeName,
(Select count(*) from table1 where condition) as data1,
(Select count(*) from table1 where condition) as data2,
(Select count(*) from table1 where condition) as data3
```

though i have seen couple of nested linq sample from these urls but still could not figure out how to construct mine.

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/09/24/nested-selects-in-linq-to-sql.aspx

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/00340c95-221a-4b16-9c47-d1acbf2415dc/linq-nested-select-issue?forum=linqtosql

http://www.mercurynewmedia.com/blog/blog-detail/mercury-new-media-blog/2014/05/19/linq-join-queries-vs-nested-sub-queries

http://www.codethinked.com/the-linq-selectmany-operator

[Nested Select linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354050/nested-select-linq-query?rq=1)

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/LINQ/Nestedquerylist.htm

so just wonder if anyone could help.

Comment: You actually shouldn't be ashamed anyway. Guess you can never learn enough and questions are the most reasonible way to get more ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example of something to do in Linq. You will find that you can do this easily and even more powerful queries if you understand two things:

1. Don't try to overly literally translate from SQL into Linq.
2. Lambdas.

The first is easy to understand but hard to carry out. Some of the Linq keywords are intentionally like SQL keywords. Linq tries to mirror some aspects of SQL without working in exactly the same way. One key difference is that with Linq, each function yields (no pun intended) a Linq object which can be passed to another Linq function. Thus filtering, transforming, aggregating, etc. can be done repeatedly in the order the programmer chooses. In SQL a single query is built up of several elements such as WHERE, FROM, some of which are optional, and the SQL engine decides in which order to evaluate them.

Get LinqPad and use it for playing with queries, and for doing database queries instead of writing SQL code in SSMS. When you have seen and written enough Linq constructs, you will no longer be writing transliterated SQL, and you will be able to switch back and forth between the two.

Secondly, make sure you understand lambdas. What does

```
x => x + 23
```

mean? What is its type? What is the type of its argument and return value? What about

```
(x, y) => x + y * 23
```

and

```
() => "Fish"
```

?

`Select` in Linq takes as argument a function. What `Select` does is the simplest possible thing to understand - it takes an iterator of input objects and a function, and returns an iterator of output objects, which are the input objects having had the function applied to them. This is actually easier to understand with a lambda than with a named function.

Remember that everything in C# has a type. A lambda has a type, even if the type is not explicit. Error messages usually tell you exactly what is wrong, except that sometimes they can be misinterpreted and seem to be pointing to exactly the wrong piece of code, and this can be very time-consuming to figure out. Break down the code you are writing into as small pieces as possible, and debug them in Linqpad.

You can get a long way with this. Try looking at a suggestion for a similar query to yours below and see if you can build on it.

```
/* A very simple dataset */
string s = "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE LAZY DOG";
var x = s.Split();

/* The letters list plays the role of your EmployeeName */
var letters = new List<String>{"A", "E", "I", "O", "U"};
var result = letters
    .Select(letter => new {letter = letter,
                           startswith = x.Count(w => w.StartsWith(letter)),
                           contains = x.Count(w => w.Contains(letter)),
                           endswith = x.Count(w => w.EndsWith(letter))});
```

If you get this far, you might want to learn more about how the Linq functions operate on iterators. Check out Jon Skeet's Edulinq series of blog posts: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts/ He reimplements Linq to show how it might be designed and how it should work.

Linqpad and Edulinq and two of the best programming resources I know of, in any language, and I recommend them in almost every Linq question I answer. Check them out.